# Paypal Payouts in Stripe?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, stripe-payments

Been working on a project. The original idea is that a user can add a product, another user will buy the product and I get for example a 10% cut of the final payment as it was processed on my site.

I have been kind of leaning towards Stripe to be honest, but I'm not sure how/if you can actually do this. I know you can do it in Paypal using 'Paypal Payouts' but I like the idea of the user not leaving the site etc.

Anyone any idea how to do it in Stripe ? Or if you can take a percentage?

Will be doing this in PHP.

Comment: Use https://stripe.com/docs/connect with https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts and you'll be able to take an application fee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Stripe Connect, thanks to those that commented.